# In R: How to subtract/divide rows in same data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame, let's say it's called my.data

```
1  Item   A   B   C
2  AAE    7   1   37
3  CCC    7   0   38
4  PPI    10  1   35
```

I want to create a row below `"AAE"` called `"AAA"` which is `"AAE" - "CCC" - "PPI"`, so for example, for column `A` we have `7-7-10 = -10`, for column `B` we have `1-0-1 = 0`, etc. To clarify, my data set is considerably bigger, and "CCC" and "PPI" are not directly under "AAE"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to firstly transpose the data.frame, do normal mutation and then transpose it back.

```
library(dplyr)
`row.names<-`(df[,-1], df[,1]) %>% t %>%
              transform(AAA = AAE - CCC - PPI) %>% 
              t %>% data.frame

      A B   C
AAE   7 1  37
CCC   7 0  38
PPI  10 1  35
AAA -10 0 -36
```

Answer (score 3):

I can get most of the way there using `Reduce` to recursively apply `-`

```
newrow <- c(Item="AAA", lapply(dat[dat$Item %in% c("AAE","CCC","PPI"),-1], Reduce, f=`-`))
rbind(dat[1,], newrow, dat[-1,])


#   Item   A B   C
#2   AAE   7 1  37
#21  AAA -10 0 -36
#3   CCC   7 0  38
#4   PPI  10 1  35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(my.data[,c("A","B","C")],2,function(x)Reduce("-",x))
  A   B   C 
-10   0 -36
```